# Reference for exercises of symplectic geometry

Tags: reference-request, symplectic-geometry

I am having trouble finding a good resource of exercises on symplectic geometry.

My references are Cannas and Dusa-Mcduff. I like Cannas's book, but its exercises are more of a supplementary nature I think. Although a great reference, I didn't like the writing of Dusa's very much, and I don't think its exercises are helping me build knowledge from a basic level upwards.

Are there some notes online which are a good resource of exercises?

Comment: There are some good exercies in Robert Bryant's notes https://services.math.duke.edu/~bryant/ParkCityLectures.pdf , and lots of challenging exercises scattered through some of Arnol'd's classic books (e.g. Mathematical Methods in Classical Mechanics, Partial Differential Equations).

Comment: There also exercises in Chris Wendl's notes which covers material similar to that in the big McDuff-Salamon book. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.1690.pdf and various other class notes that people have written.